# Dynamic Programming Maximum Profit for Movers in 2 cities

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

There is a moving company. It operates in two cities. They wish to maximize profit. Given are 2 arrays representing the two cities. The value at position i in each of the arrays indicates the maximum profit to be made in the city that day. If they work in city A on day i, and city B on day i+1, there is a cost associated with travelling between the 2 cities c. We need to use Dynamic Programming to find the maximum profit to be made. Here is an example:

```
A = {10, 20, 30}
B = {-10, 50, 20}
c = 20
optimal solution = (10 + (50 - 20) + 20) = 10 + 30 + 20 = 60
```

I think this is similar to weighted interval schedule OR the subset sum problem (knapsack). Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I need to find the recurrence relation(s), time complexity of the algorithm and then prove the correctness. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To represent this problem better,

- Let `A` be the profit matrix where `A[c]` is the profit array for city `c` (`c = 0` for the first city, `c = 1` for the second, and so on).
- Let `P(i, c)` be the optimal profit up to and including day `i` such that the moving company end up in city `c` on day `i`.
- Let `C(c', c)` is the cost of moving from a city `c'` to a city `c`.

This setup allows us to generalize the solution to an arbitrary number of cities.

In order to maximize `P(i, c)`, we have to consider all possible cities that the movers could be in on the previous day `i-1` and choose the maximal option. These possibilities include the movers being in the same city on the previous day, and moving from another city the previous day while incurring a moving cost. Hence

```
P(i, c) = max(P(i-1, c), max(P(i-1, c') + C(c', c) for all cities c' != c)) + A[c][i]
```

The first argument in the outer `max` (`P(i-1, c)`) considers the case where the movers were in the same city on the previous day, and the second argument (the inner `max`) evaluates and maximizes the profits (including moving costs) if the movers were in a different city on the previous day.

The final answer is simply `max(P(n, x) for all cities x)` where `n` is the last day (considering all possible cities the movers could end up in on the final day).

In your example, city A == city 0, city B == city 1, profit matrix `A = [[10, 20, 30], [-10, 50, 20]]`, and `C(0, 1) = C(1, 0) = 20`.

**EDIT:**

The time complexity will be `O(nc)`, where `n` is the number of days and `c` is the number of cities. If the number of cities is fixed, then the time complexity is `O(n)`.

Proving correctness can be done using induction. Assume that `P(i-1, x)` is maximal for all cities `x`. Then show that `P(i, c)` for some city `c` as defined above is maximal. There are two possibilities for the maximal solution:

- The movers were in the same city `c` on day `i-1`
- The movers were in a different city `c'` on day `i-1`.

Now all you have to show is that the recurrence defined above will give you the correct solution in both these cases.

Comment: This is super helpful! Please see edits to the original question! Thank you!

Comment: @lazycamper edited, please look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use a bottom up DP here.

Keep optimal sub solutions from right to left. For every new element, of say array `A` is,

```
dp1[i] = Math.max(A[i] + dp1[i+1],A[i] + dp2[i+1] - C);
```

where `dp1` is the maximum to keep for array `A` and `dp2` is maximum to keep for array `B`.

**Snippet:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {10,20,00};
        int[] B = {-10,50,20};
        int C = 20;
        System.out.println(solve(A,B,C));
    }

    private static int solve(int[] A,int[] B,int C){
        int len = A.length;
        int[] dp1 = new int[len];
        int[] dp2 = new int[len];
        dp1[len-1] = A[len-1];
        dp2[len-1] = B[len-1];
        int max = Math.max(dp1[len-1],dp2[len-1]);
        for(int i=A.length-2;i >= 0;--i){
            dp1[i] = Math.max(A[i] + dp1[i+1],A[i] + dp2[i+1] - C);
            dp2[i] = Math.max(B[i] + dp2[i+1],B[i] + dp1[i+1] - C);
            max = Math.max(dp1[i],dp2[i]);
        }
        return max;
    }

}
```

**Demo:** https://onlinegdb.com/BJFptkHDU

Comment: This is correct I believe! Please see edits to the original question! Thank you!

Comment: @lazycamper  Time complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You want a DP solution but I think the greedy approach is more appropriate for this problem. here is the greedy solution:

```
        int[] a = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
        int[] b = new int[] { -10, 50, 20 };

        int n = a.Length;
        bool aSelected = a[0] > b[0];
        int c = 20;
        int profit = Math.Max(a[0], b[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            int temp;
            if (aSelected)
            {
                temp = Math.Max(a[i], b[i] - c);
                if (temp != a[i])
                {
                    aSelected = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp = Math.Max(a[i] - c, b[i]);
                if (temp != b[i])
                {
                    aSelected = true;
                }
            }

            profit += temp;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(profit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say at ith day if he's in city A, then he has 2 choices he can collect the profit on city A to travel to city B. Mathematically we can express it as

fA(i) = max(fA(i-1)+A[i],fB(i-1))

Bottom up approach where he can come from city B without collecting anything or collect profit in city A.

similarly,

fB(i) = max(fB(i-1)+B[i], fA(i-1))

Answer (score -1):

Your solution doesn't work if there are cases that equals like the examples:

```
a={1,5,3,9}
b={6,2,3,1}
k=3
```

- Expected: 20
- Your output: 17